# Google Spreadsheet, for each distinct item in column A, Sum columns B through E

Tags: google-sheets

I'm trying to make a spreadsheet for Zelda: Breath of the Wild where I count how many of each item I need to build a bunch of different armor sets.

Here is a link to the spreadsheet I'm working with, read only: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/161OmMq46BJuXN5KopDFvs7RwRFinKIM8AoKYhiB0ew0/edit?usp=sharing

Column A has a list of material names, and some of them repeat.
Columns B through E have a number indicating how many of the item in Column A is needed.
Each column, B through E, represents a level 1 through 4.
Column F has a `=SUM(B{ROWNUM}:E{ROWNUM}`

So I can have:

```
         | Level 1 | Level 2 | Level 3 | Level 4 | Total
--------------------------------------------------------
Item one |    5    |    10   |    0    |    0    |   15
--------------------------------------------------------
Item two |    0    |    5    |    8    |    0    |   13
--------------------------------------------------------
Item one |    0    |    0    |    10   |    15   |   25
```

And what I want is:

```
         | Total
-------------------
Item one |  40  
-------------------
Item two |  13
```

I'm trying now to do it with Google Script, but I've never used it before, so I don't have anything to show for that as of now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Query should do it. I assume your data is in Sheet1 and query is in another sheet.

```
 =query(Sheet1!A1:F4,"select A, sum(F) group by A label sum(F) 'Total'")
```